# Como llamar la variable donde se guarda la cantidad de lux del sensor tsl2561?

Tags: arduino

Buenas compañeros, este es mi primer pregunta y soy nuevo en esto....sin mas.
 Cómo puedo llamar la variable del sensor `tsl2561` donde se guardan los datos de **lux**? tengo entendido que está en la librería de dicho sensor pero no sé como llamarla y necesito compararla con otra variable. 
adjunto enlace del sensor por si necesitan hecharle un ojo.

Visit: [Enlace](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TSL2561.pdf)

gracias

Comment: En el github de la librería tienes [un ejemplo de uso](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_TSL2561/blob/master/examples/sensorapi/sensorapi.ino)

Comment: excelente, ese ya lo tengo. lo que necesito es saber que comando o parametro debo usar para llamar la variable donde se guardan los datos de lux para iguarlarla a otra variable que yo elija